# How to put and get the current date by using simple database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, datetime

I'm a beginner and don't know how to insert and get the current date by using database.

For an insert into the database, I use a button for adding the information. Here is the full code:

```
public void Badd_Click(View view) {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Demo (event, venue, amount, textView) VALUES ('" + tEvent.getText().toString() + "'," + "'" + tLocation.getText().toString() + "'," + "'" + tAmount.getText().toString() +"' )");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Create record successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Then, for showing the information inserted into the database, I also use a button:

```
public void Btnshow_Click(View view){
    String str = "";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    for(int i = 0; i<c.getCount();i++){
        str+="ID: "+c.getString(0)+"\n";
        str+="Name : "+c.getString(1)+"\n";
        str+="Location : "+c.getString(2)+"\n";
        str+="Amount : "+c.getString(3)+"\n\n";
        c.moveToNext();
    }
```

I have searched for many solutions, but I am unable to do it successfully.
Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use below two methods to save and retrieve date from database in the format you want.

```
public static String getDbDateString(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    return sdf.format(date);
}

public static Date getDateFromDb(String dateText) {
    SimpleDateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    try {
        return dbDateFormat.parse(dateText);
    } catch ( ParseException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can get current date with below code:

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

To add to database:

```
public void addDate() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("key", "value");

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(table_name, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

To read from database:

```
public Date getDate(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name,
            new String[]{column_id,
                    column_date_value},
            column_id + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();


    assert cursor != null;
    return new Date(cursor.getString(index_column_date));
}
```

Comment: All these code should put it into MainActivity? or some code put into DBhelper.java? If put into MainActivity is it crash with my original code?

Comment: You can have them in your DBhelper.java file

Comment: Concerning about two method if I use getDbDateString(Date date) is it needs to use with Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) ? Also, about add and show codes, If i would like to put it in my code how to improve the code with my original code? So, it can put it into MainActivity not neccessary to put into DBhelper?